# PostgreSQL - Update not working inside function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am creating a web app that handles coupons. When a user claims a coupon the coupon batch count "should" be updated, and a new coupon is created.

For some reason the UPDATE query does not work inside my PostgreSQL function. Everything else works fine.

I have a coupon batch:

```
CREATE TABLE public.batch (
    batch_id integer NOT NULL,
    template_id integer NOT NULL,
    created_count integer NOT NULL,
    claimed_count integer NOT NULL,
    redeemed_count integer NOT NULL,
    start_date date NOT NULL,
    expiry_date date NOT NULL,
    status_id integer NOT NULL
);
```

When a coupon is "claimed" from a batch a new record is created in coupons:

```
CREATE TABLE public.coupons (
    coupon_id integer NOT NULL,
    code character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    customer_id integer NOT NULL,
    batch_id integer NOT NULL,
    is_redeemed boolean NOT NULL,
    date_claimed date NOT NULL,
    date_used date,
    redeemed_discount integer,
    purchased_item character varying(30)
);
```

The postgres function to claim a coupon from a batch:

```
/*Claim a coupon */
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION claim_from_batch(businessID INTEGER,batchID INTEGER, customerID INTEGER) 
    RETURNS INTEGER AS $$

DECLARE
    couponBatchID INTEGER;
    newCouponID INTEGER;
BEGIN
    PERFORM update_batch_status();

   /*Check if the batch is available to the customer*/
    SELECT INTO couponBatchID batches.batch_id 
    FROM get_customer_available_batches(customerID) as batches 
    WHERE batches.batch_id = batchID
    AND batches.business_id = businessID;

    IF couponBatchID IS NOT NULL THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'success';
        /*update the coupons_claimed value*/
        UPDATE batch SET claimed_count =  cp.count 
        FROM (SELECT COUNT(coupon_id) FROM coupons WHERE batch_id = batchID) AS cp
        WHERE batch_id = batchID;

        /*Create the coupon*/
        INSERT INTO coupons(code,customer_id,batch_id,is_redeemed,date_claimed)
        VALUES('PLACEHOLDER', customerID,batchID,false,NOW())
        RETURNING coupons.coupon_id INTO newCouponID;
         IF newCouponID IS NOT NULL THEN
            RETURN newCouponID;
         END IF;
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'failed';
        RETURN -1;
    END IF;
END $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The strangest thing for me is that when I run the update query with a hard-coded batch_id number, outside the function, in the query builder of pg-admin, the value gets updated correctly.

I tried multiple variations of this and and searched through the internet, 
I also tried separating the update to a separate function and call it inside the claim function. Nothing works.

I can't debug the reason why this is not working. I am still a CS student so excuse any other obvious mistakes I might have missed.

I tried changing the update portion of the function to:

```
UPDATE batch
 SET claimed_count = (SELECT COUNT(coupon_id) 
                      FROM coupons 
                      WHERE batch_id = batchID)
 WHERE batch_id = batchID;
```

P.S I am not sure if Updating the claimed_count value like this, is the best approach, since the value simply increases by one (1). But it made sense because if I later wanted to (possibly) return a coupon to the batch, I would need the value to be updated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is hard to debug without access to your system or test data that exhibit the problem.

Comment: Perhaps there is no such row in `batches` with that batchID.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ There is though. I tried the query outside the function with correct values. And I called the function with correct values as well.

Comment: Perhaps the IF ELSE is not designed properly? Does the INSERT INTO coupons happen?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes. Insert happens. the update does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I recently had this same issue. It turns out the cause for me was the RLS update policy on the table I was trying to update.

You'll want to make sure the RLS policy allows the user executing the function to also update the table, or mark your function as [`security definer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY) to bypass RLS.